# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bucket'

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to create a s3 bucket but I keep getting this error code:

File "/home/ec2-user/environment/homework_1.py", line 64, in create_bucket
region = self.bucket.meta.client.meta.region_name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bucket'

My code is as follows:

```
def create_bucket(self=None, region_override=None):
    """Create an Amazon S3 bucket in the default Region for the account or in the
    specified Region."""
    
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    bucket = None
    
    if region_override is not None:
        region = region_override
    else:
        region = self.bucket.meta.client.meta.region_name
    try:
        self.bucket.create(CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': region})

        self.bucket.wait_until_exists()
        logger.info("Created bucket '%s' in region=%s", self.bucket.name, region)
        
    except ClientError as error:
       logger.exception("Couldn't create bucket named '%s' in region=%s.", self.bucket.name, region)
       raise error
```

I've tried to run the code without that particular line in the code thinking that would fix it but ended up with the same error message on "self.bucket.create(CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': region})". I'm new to cloud programming. Can someone help?

Comment: What is your `self` variable supposed to mean? Right now you are calling the function `create_bucket` with `self` as None, so naturally `self.bucket` doesn't exist which throws the error.

Comment: presumably, given the use of the `self`, this is a method of a class ?  if so, like the above comment... it will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to use this function as a method of a class where self refers to the class instantiation. Eg:

```
import boto3

class YourClass:
    def __init__(self, bucket_name):
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(self.bucket_name)

    def create_bucket(self, region_override=None):
        ... your function code
```

Then instantiate your class and call the function like this:

```
myBucketName = "SomeNewBucket"
myBucketClass = YourClass(myBucketName)

myBucketClass.create_bucket()
```

For documentation see: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket